# Не получается переместить и изменить включаемую область в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Изучаю Битрикс. В тестовом задании требуется вставить включаемую область с текстом в определённое место.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как здесь изменить текст и отформатировать его?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем надо переместить включаемую область вот сюда. Потому что когда я её создавал, она появилась внизу. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Если изучаете битрикс в качестве разработчика, то рекомендую править файлы включаемой области по FTP.
2. Включаемая область должна отображаться только на странице каталога или на всех, где есть левая колонка?
   Если только на странице каталога, то нужно разместить вызов включаемой области после умного фильтра (судя по скриншоту).
   А если на любых страницах, то в шаблоне, где размещена левая колонка.